# Map a function's argument, which is a lambda, to a tuple?

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, reduce

This is the function call below and I'm trying to construct the function `fee`, I need to map the tuple using functional prog. so that it turns into `(6-7)**2 + (7-1)**2 + (1-4)**2`, and the last one is `(4-6)**2`. Then I will sum these and return this value in `fee`.

```
fee((6, 7, 1, 4), lambda x, y: (x-y) ** 2)
```

Comment: What is a function fee?

Comment: Can toy clarify what you are asking using an input/output example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Cheese. SO is a question-and-answer site. Readers, such as yourself, ask questions and other readers attempt to answer the questions. Your post is missing a key element: a question. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: fee = lambda t: sum((x-y)**2 for x, y in zip(t, t[1:]+(t[0],)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with python [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) :

```
>>> def fee(tup):
...    return sum(map(lambda x,y:(x-y)**2,tup,tup[1:]+(tup[0],)))
```

Demo :

```
>>> t=(6, 7, 1, 4)
>>> fee(t)
50
```

You can use `map` function to apply the `lambda` function on pairs and sum the result :

```
>>> zip(t,t[1:]+(t[0],))
[(6, 7), (7, 1), (1, 4), (4, 6)]
```

Instead of `map` as a more efficient way you can use `zip` and a generator expression within `sum` :

```
>>> def fee(tup):
...    return sum((x-y)**2 for x,y in zip(tup,tup[1:]+(tup[0],))))
```

Comment: You don't have to zip explicitly. Since the first argument to `map` is a function that takes two arguments, you can just pass the two tuples as separate arguments: `map(lambda x, y: ..., tup, tup[1:] + (tup[0],))`.

Comment: The list comprehension makes it a moot point, though :) That's very much better than using `map` here.

Comment: In your first solution with sum and map, will the map take any tuple length?

Comment: @Cheese Yes, actually it's depends on your memory limit!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of `zip`, `map`, and `sum`:

```
def fee(vals):
    x1 = zip(vals, vals[1:] + [vals[0]])
    x2 = map(lambda t: (t[0] - t[1]) ** 2, x1)
    return sum(x2)
```

Explanation:

1. `zip(vals, vals[:-1] + [vals[0]])` combines `vals` into a list of 2-tuple pairs.
2. `map(lambda t: (t[0] - t[1]) ** 2, x1)` performs the mathematical operation on each 2-tuple element.
3. `sum(x2)` sums the results of #2 together.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
from itertools import tee

try:
    from itertools import izip as zip  # Python 2
except ImportError:
    pass  # Python 3


# An itertools recipe
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def fee(args, func):
    last_value = func(args[-1], args[0])
    return sum(func(x, y) for x, y in pairwise(args)) + last_value


print(fee((6, 7, 1, 4), lambda x, y: (x-y) ** 2))  # 50
```